# Calculating sum of nested fields with date_histogram aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble getting the sum of a nested field in Elasticsearch using a date_histogram, and I'm hoping somebody can lend me a hand.

I have a mapping that looks like this:

```
"client" : {
  // various irrelevant stuff here...

  "associated_transactions" : {
    "type" : "nested",
    "include_in_parent" : true,
    "properties" : {
      "amount" : {
        "type" : "double"
      },
      "effective_at" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get a date_histogram that shows total revenue by month across all clients--i.e. a time series showing the sum associated_transactions.amount in a histogram determined by associated_transactions.effective_date.  I tried running this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    // ...
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "revenue": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "interval": "month",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "field": "associated_transactions.effective_at"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "monthly_revenue": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "associated_transactions.amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the sum it's giving me isn't right.  It seems that what ES is doing is finding all clients who have any transaction in a given month, then summing all of the transactions (from any time) for those clients.  That is, it's a sum of the amount spent in the lifetime of a client who made a purchase in a given month, not the sum of purchases in a given month.

Is there any way to get the data I'm looking for, or is this a limitation in how ES handles nested fields?

Thanks very much in advance for your help!

David

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
{
  "query": {
    // ...
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "revenue": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "interval": "month",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "field": "associated_transactions.effective_at"

        "aggs": {
          "monthly_revenue": {
            "sum": {
              "field": "associated_transactions.amount"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i.e. move the "aggs" key into the "date_histogram" field.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question while trying to solve similar problem with my implementation of ES.

It seems that currently Elasticsearch looks at position of aggregation in the JSON body request tree - not inheritance of its objects and filelds. So you should not put your sum aggregation "inside" "date_histogram", but place it outside on the same JSON tree level.

This worked for me:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "histogram_aggregation": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date_vield",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "views": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "the_vield_i_want_to_sum"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    #some query
    }
```

OP made mistake of placing his sum aggregation inside date histogram aggregation.